# iPod won't sleep when connected to debugger

Tags: xcode, debugging, ipod-touch, auto-lock

I've got my iPod connected to my debugger running in XCode. The auto-lock is set to 1 minute. When the debugger is not running, the iPod goes to sleep after 1 minute of inactivity. However, when the debugger is running, my iPod won't sleep.

This is frustrating because I want to see what methods get called on my app when the iPod goes to sleep.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Good question. It is still an issue 10 years later.  I would like to test some stuff from the app automatically going inactive by the phone sleeping, and the issues I am investigating are specific with auto lock, and while both using the auto lock feature and lock button cause the same notifications/callbacks, how can we be sure there are no behind the scenes system differences?  The behavior I am investigating is claimed to be different between the two...  Anyway, good question!

Answer (score 10):

Just lock it manually by pressing the top power/lock button. It calls the same methods (applicationDidEnterBackground:) on iOS devices which support multitasking.

Comment: Do you have any documentation to verify that pressing the top lock button is the same as the phone going to sleep from inactivity?

Comment: i used the debugger. When the top lock button was clicked applicationdidEnterBackground was called